# Terminator not executing command while Lxterminal does

Tags: terminator, fluxbox, lxterminal

Using Ubuntu 12.04 with fluxbox, installed from mini iso, no DE.

The problem is as follows:

In my fluxbox menu I have the following two lines:

```
[exec] (Textfile) {/usr/bin/terminator -e /usr/bin/nano /home/me/Documents/Directory/Textfile}
[exec] (Textfile) {/usr/bin/lxterminal -e /usr/bin/nano /home/me/Documents/Directory/Textfile}
```

If I use lxterminal the textfile opens in the terminal in the editor nano.
If I use terminator the textfile doesn't open and neither does terminator.
Nano opens when I use the following line:

```
[exec] (Textfile) {/usr/bin/terminator -e /usr/bin/nano}
```

If terminator is already open and I type:

```
/usr/bin/nano /home/me/Documents/Directory/Textfile
```

the textfile does open in nano.

Does anybody know how to make terminator act the same as lxterminal?

Comment: If `lxterminal` does work as you say, I'm inclined to think it's a bug. The way you have written the commands, you should be using `-x` instead of `-e`: `lxterminal -x nano /some/path` and `terminator -x nano /some/path`. `-e` should be used so that the command is a single string: `terminator -e "nano /some/path"`

Comment: @ muru, Thanks you are right, problem solved. When you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `lxterminal` does work as you say, I'm inclined to think it's a bug.

The way you have written the commands, you should be using `-x` instead of `-e`:

```
terminator -x nano /some/path
```

If `-e` is used, the full command has to be given as a single string:

```
terminator -e "nano /some/path"
```

From [the `terminator` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/terminator.1.html):

```
-e, --command=COMMAND
      Runs  the  specified  command  instead  of your default shell or
      profile specified command

-x, --execute COMMAND [ARGS]
      Runs the rest of the command line instead of your default  shell
      or profile specified command.
```

Terminator is similar to XFCE Terminal or GNOME Terminal in this respect.

On second thought, it seems `lxterminal` is following `xterm`'s behaviour, but not documenting it clearly. From [`man lxterminal`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/lxterminal.1.html):

```
-e STRING --command=STRING --command STRING
   This option specifies the program (and its command line arguments)
   to be run in the terminal. Except in the --command= form, this must
   be the last option on the command line.
```

[`man xterm`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xterm.1.html) says it more clearly:

```
-e program [ arguments ... ]
       This  option  specifies  the  program  (and  its  command  line
       arguments)  to  be  run  in the xterm window.  It also sets the
       window title and icon name to be the basename  of  the  program
       being  executed  if  neither -T nor -n are given on the command
       line.  This must be the last option on the command line.
```